# xcodeの以下のエラーの意味を教えて欲しいです。

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios10

外部の画像を読み込み表示するプログラムで2行目の実行時にエラーが出ます。
※XcodeのバージョンはVersion 8.2.1になります。
※画像の表示は問題なくされているようです。

```
let url = URL(string: "***.jpg")!
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
let img = UIImage(data:imageData!)
let imgView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image:img)
imgView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:300, height:300)
self.view.addSubview(imgView);
```

エラーは以下のような内容ですが、意味がわからず、無視して良いのかもわかりません。
どなたか原因や意味わかりますでしょうか？

```
2017-01-24 16:50:51.273542 loadMovie2[2196:135371] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-01-24 16:50:51.276346 loadMovie2[2196:135371] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2017-01-24 16:50:51.276600 loadMovie2[2196:135371] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-01-24 16:50:51.277360 loadMovie2[2196:135371] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010fc4b666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff29006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff06555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff05572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff04298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff1fae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff1f510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010ff371f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f9c8978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f9f20cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f9cfe17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f9d0b4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f9d3385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f9d3059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010fd9b4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010fd99341 start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: Xcodeの詳細なバージョンを教えてくださいませんか？ (追記して編集することができます。もちろんコメントでも結構です。)

Comment: ありがとうござます！　追記編集させていただきましたが、バージョンはVersion 8.2.1になります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SO_NOAPNFALLBK`に着目して探したところ、英語版のStackOverflowで似たような質問がありました。もしかすると参考になるかもしれません。

> 1. Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
> 2. Open the Arguments tab
> 3. Add the Environment Variable :- OS_ACTIVITY_MODE is disable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545603/error-protocol-not-available-dumping-backtrace

Comment: ありがとうございます！　無事ログが出なくなりました。不要なログを非表示の以下の記事でも取り上げられているようで、大変助かりました。http://qiita.com/plasticstraw/items/77d93cdb644dc66c48f8

Comment: ただ、何を意味しているのかはまだ、分からないのですが、分からなくても問題ない内容でしょうか？？

Comment: 参考: StackOverflow上に、[良く似た別の質問がある](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-8-logs)ようです。 その[回答の1つ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39651073/5989200)にリンクされている[ツイート](https://twitter.com/rustyshelf/status/775505191160328194)によると、Xcode 8.1ではfixされているようです。

Comment: 私も残念ながら、具体的に何を意味しているかはわかりかねますが、いくつかのリンクを合わせて読んでいる限りだと、`日時 プロセス名[プロセスID:スレッドID] メッセージ`といった構成になっているように見えますね。

次のリンクなどを見ました。 [Smarter Debugging with Unified Logging & Activity Tracing - Art & Logic: Custom Software Development](https://artandlogic.com/2016/07/smarter-debugging-unified-logging-activity-tracing/), [Activity Tracing · objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/activity-tracing/), [714_ActivityTracing _DF - 714_fix_bugs_faster_using_activity_tracing.pdf](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/714xx1h4szxdnyz/714/714_fix_bugs_faster_using_activity_tracing.pdf)

Comment: 回答に記載されているStackOverflowのリンクの回答の中に以下のように説明されているものがありました。「本来socketのオプションにSO_NOAPNFALLBKは存在しない。おそらくAppleが独自にプッシュ通知サービスのために拡張しているのではないか。プッシュ通知サービスはシミュレータでは動作しないため、このようなエラーが発生する」。少し意訳が多めですが。

Comment: みなさま、ありがとうございます。 maotさまのご指摘の内容であればシュミレータでの問題だけであって本番では問題ないということかもしれませんね、恐縮ですが実機での確認ができておりませんので、確認できましたら追記させていただきます。